# Isometries of manifolds with non-positive sectional curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, negative-curvature

It is known since Bochner that for M compact with negative Ricci curvature, the group of isometries is discreet and hence finite. Are there any generalizations to compact non-positive sectional curvature manifolds? Of course,  $T^n$ is a counterexample for strictly 0 curvature case. But what about sectional curvature <0 on a non-empty open set, and vanishing elsewhere?

As I understand Bochner's argument does break down in this case.

Known counterexamples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bochner's theorem extends to nonpositive Ricci to give:

> If $(M,g)$ is compact and has $\textrm{Ric}\leq 0$ then any Killing vector $X$ is parallel and $\textrm{Ric}(X,X) = 0$.

See Petersen (3rd ed) Theorem 8.2.2.

Thus if $(M,g)$ is compact and has $\textrm{Ric}\leq 0$ with $<0$ then $X = 0$.

Comment: Thanks, I will need to think about that for a bit. What about if M has (totally geodesic) boundary? Sorry if these are elementary questions, not really my subject.

Comment: Ok I read Petersen. Looks good. It seems like in case the manifold has boundary the argument would have problems, since it is using the maximum principle for the Laplacian.

Comment: Do you want to assume anything about the killing vector at the boundary? I think if the KVF is tangent to the boundary then you should be able to make it work. But with no boundary conditions there must be a counterexample.

Comment: No additional assumptions on KVF.